# upload image to s3 bucket node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having some problems uploading my image from a form to my s3 bucket. At present part of the image gets uploaded, so for example 19kb instead of the full 272kb, if i try and open the image from within my bucket it's broken

```
app.post('/admin/addClub', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) {
  res.redirect('/admin');
  return;
}

// Upload image to S3
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} } )
var data = { Key: req.body.imageBanner, // file from form
             Body: req.body.imageBanner, // Not sure here
             ACL: "public-read",
             ContentType: helper.getContentTypeByFile(req.body.imageBanner)
           };
s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
  if (err) 
  { console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
    res.redirect('/admin/main');
  } else {
    console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
    res.redirect('/admin/main');
  }
});
```

Can anybody advise what i need to pass through for the `Body` key? as i think this must be my issue

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but that `res.redirect('/admin/main');` could be outside the if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to integrate the express-fileupload package that allows you to receive file uploads on Express.

To install run: `npm install --save express-fileupload`

Then you'll need to pass `req.files.imageBanner.data` (supposing your file upload field looks like `<input name="imageBanner" type="file" />`) as the `Body` parameter. Here's how it should look:

```
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/admin/addClub', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/admin');
    return;
  }

  // Upload image to S3
  var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET, Key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} } )
  var data = { Key: req.body.imageBanner, // file from form
               Body: req.files.imageBanner.data,
               ACL: "public-read",
               ContentType: helper.getContentTypeByFile(req.body.imageBanner)
             };
  s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data){
    if (err) 
    { console.log('Error uploading data: ', data); 
      res.redirect('/admin/main');
    } else {
      console.log('succesfully uploaded the image!');
      res.redirect('/admin/main');
    }
  });
});
```

You can find the documentation for the express-fileupload package here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at the package

Comment: so i seem to be getting `Cannot read property 'imageBanner' of null` , `imageBanner` being `<input name="imageBanner" type="file" />`

Comment: You need to require and use the express-fileupload component, as per the documentation. I've updated my answer to reflect that (it's near the top of the code I shared).

Comment: yes, I am doing that but still get the error, any further suggestions ?

Comment: ok so i've added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form...seems to have helped